# QMenu Icon background color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qmenu

I'm trying to apply custom QSS styles to the menu, but the icon that is in the selected menu item has non-transparent background color. How can I make it transparent?

Screenshot

[image]

```
QMenu
{
    padding: 0.1em;
    border: 0.05em solid #1f2530;
    background-color: #343b49;
}

QMenu::item
{
    color: #ededed;
    selection-background-color: #1f2530;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better you customize (make image transparent) with Photoshop then use it in your project.

Anyway you could use this code to fill some pixels of your image:

```
QImage myImage;
myImage.load("D:/1.jpeg");
myImage = myImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
         myImage.setPixel(i,y,qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
myImage.save("D:/2.jpeg");
```

Load your image with QImage, convert image format, fill some pixels, finally Save image.

Comment: The image is already transparent and looks as expected if I'm not applying QSS styles